# How to Accept License Agreement while installing exe file using powershell

Tags: powershell, installation, command-line-interface, exe

I am trying to install a .exe file without any User Intervention using Powershell.

I have my file in desktop.

The command I tried in powershell is

`Start-Process -Wait -Filepath "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\app.exe" -ArgumentList "S" -PassThru`

Still I am getting License Agreement window. Is there any command to Accept the license in powershell??

Comment: if you run the installer directly with that one option ... does it install without user interaction? not all apps have a true silent install.

Comment: No it doesn't. License Agreement window pops up.

Comment: then you need to find out how that specific app handles the license agreement. it may not be possible ... but you will need to research it. perhaps you can call their tech support?

Comment: Just `S` as a command-line parameter looks strange. Are you sure it isn't `/S` or `-S`?

Comment: I tried both it's not working.

Comment: run the app.exe from a commandline like `app.exe /?`. If you're lucky it will list all possible switches. Hopefully, there is something like `/accepteula`

Comment: That didn't worked. Contacted Vendor, This App isn't really meant for any kind of automation.